# Including both equation numbering and remarks in align environment

Tags: numbering, align, tags

I'm trying to write sequent proofs with aligned formulae in the center, equation numbers aligned left, and remarks aligned right. Example of what I want below:

[image: Example]

But from what I've seen around StackExchange, tags on a line of an alignment replace the numbering of that line, as well as share the same alignment setting. Here's a sample of what I'm having trouble with.

```
\documentclass[leqno]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\begin{document}
 \begin{align}
  Rab 
  &\implies Rab                                \tag{R0}
  \\ &\implies Rab,\neg Rab                    \tag{R2a}
  \\ &\implies Rab, \exists y \neg Ray   
  \\ \neg \exists y \neg Ray 
  &\implies Rab   
  \\ \forall y Ray 
  &\implies Rab      
  \\ \exists x \forall y Rxy 
  &\implies Rab   
  \\ \exists x \forall y Rxy 
  &\implies \exists x Rxb
  \\ \exists x \forall y Rxy, \neg \exists x Rxb 
  &\implies 
  \\ \exists x \forall y Rxy, \exists y \neg \exists x Rxy 
  &\implies 
  \\ \exists x \forall y Rxy 
  &\implies \neg \exists y \neg \exists x Rxy 
  \\ \exists x \forall y Rxy 
  &\implies \forall y \exists x Rxy \qedhere
 \end{align}
\end{document}
```

An image of the corresponding output:

[image: Output]

Answer (score 1):

Only the first 3 lines modified, but the rest should be easy. Alas, more ampersands needed.

```
\documentclass[leqno]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\begin{document}
 \begin{align}
  Rab 
  &\implies Rab                                &\text{(RO)}&
  \\ &\implies Rab,\neg Rab            &        \text{(R2aa)}&
  \\ &\implies Rab, \exists y \neg Ray  & \text{(and so on)}& 
  \\ \neg \exists y \neg Ray 
  &\implies Rab   
  \\ \forall y Ray 
  &\implies Rab      
  \\ \exists x \forall y Rxy 
  &\implies Rab   
  \\ \exists x \forall y Rxy 
  &\implies \exists x Rxb
  \\ \exists x \forall y Rxy, \neg \exists x Rxb 
  &\implies 
  \\ \exists x \forall y Rxy, \exists y \neg \exists x Rxy 
  &\implies 
  \\ \exists x \forall y Rxy 
  &\implies \neg \exists y \neg \exists x Rxy 
  \\ \exists x \forall y Rxy 
  &\implies \forall y \exists x Rxy \qedhere
 \end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do that very easily with the `flalign` environment:

```
\documentclass[leqno]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\begin{document}

 \begin{flalign}
  & & Rab &\implies Rab & \text{(R0)}
  \\ & & &\implies Rab,\neg Rab & \text{(R2a)}
  \\ & & &\implies Rab, \exists y \neg Ray
  \\ & & \neg \exists y \neg Ray &\implies Rab
  \\& & \forall y Ray &\implies Rab
  \\& & \exists x \forall y Rxy &\implies Rab
  \\ & & \exists x \forall y Rxy &\implies \exists x Rxb
  \\& & \exists x \forall y Rxy, \neg \exists x Rxb &\implies
  \\ & & \exists x \forall y Rxy, \exists y \neg \exists x Rxy &\implies
  \\ & & \exists x \forall y Rxy &\implies \neg \exists y \neg \exists x Rxy
  \\ & & \exists x \forall y Rxy &\implies \forall y \exists x Rxy \qedhere
 \end{flalign}

\end{document}
```

[image]